# Do these formatting conventions mean something?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

```
String.Format("{0:d}", item.ReleaseDate)
```

In the above code 'd' is used for location holder for `item.ReleaseDate`

Whereas in

```
String.Format("{0:c}", item.Price)
```

'c' is used for placeholder for `item.Price`.

Are there any constraints that only d should be used for `DateTime` and c should be used for price?

Pardon me am a noob in technical conventions. Please correct me in the conventions too.

Comment: Actually, {0} is the placeholder and the d or c is just a semaphore to tell the string.Format how to format the given input. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

d for decimal, c for currency in your example. Meaning can be changed depending on the variable that will be used in place of the placeholder

http://sharpertutorials.com/string-formatting/

And, these conventions are very much language specific. Rules of one language may not be valid for others.

Comment: Sarwar Erfan gave you a good link. I could only add that the conventions for datetimes support even more features. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx and http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/